# XQuery iteration in non seqential manner

Tags: java, xml-parsing, xquery

I have a xml documents with following tags

```
          <User>aaaa</User>
          <User>bbbb</User>
          <User>cccc</User>
          <User>dddd</User>
          <User>eeee</User>
          <User>cccc</User>
          <User>uuuu</User>
```

While iterating it using for loop  the data is **not coming** in order

eg:

Some times getting

```
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
dddd
```

and some time it shows like this

```
uuuu
bbbb
cccc
dddd
```

How can i iterate in sequential manner ? **Or provide name of any sequential xml parsers**.

Thanks in advance

Comment: When retrieved from the document using a path expression, you would expect the data in [document order](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#id-document-order). But you can get better advice, if you provide the code fragment that does not do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example where the results reflect the original ordering of the elements in the source XML document:

```
for $x in /*/*
  return
    $x
```

When this XQuery is performed on the following document (the provided XML fragment, wrapped into a single top element to make it a well-formed XML document):

```
<t>
    <User>aaaa</User>
    <User>bbbb</User>
    <User>cccc</User>
    <User>dddd</User>
    <User>eeee</User>
    <User>cccc</User>
    <User>uuuu</User>
</t>
```

the result is:

```
<User>aaaa</User>
<User>bbbb</User>
<User>cccc</User>
<User>dddd</User>
<User>eeee</User>
<User>cccc</User>
<User>uuuu</User>
```

Comment: Thanks, is the loop provide above result in same order for every time ? (I think XQuery loops are non sequential)

Comment: @nidhin: The results must have exactly the same order as shown in this answer. This doesn't mean at all that the processing is performed exactly in the same order.